# LDA vs Word2Vec. Which is the right solution for predicting recipients of a message?

Tags: nlp, data-science, word2vec, lda

I'm investigating various NLP algorithms and tools to solve the following problem; NLP newbie here, so pardon my question if it's too basic.

Let's say, I have a messaging app where users can send text messages to one or more people. When the user types a message, I want the app to suggest to the user who the potential recipients of the message are?

If user "A" sends a lot of text messages regarding "cats" to user "B" and some messages to user "C" and sends a lot of messages regarding "politics" to user "D", then next time user types the message about "cats" then the app should suggest "B" and "C" instead of "D".

So I'm doing some research on topic modeling and word embeddings and see that LDA and Word2Vec are the 2 probable algorithms I can use.

Wanted to pick your brain on which one you think is more suitable for this scenario.

One idea I have is, extract topics using LDA from the previous messages and rank the recipients of the messages based on the # of times a topic has been discussed (ie, the message sent) in the past. If I have this mapping of the topic and a sorted list of users who you talk about it (ranked based on frequency), then when the user types a message, I can again run topic extraction on the message, predict what the message is about and then lookup the mapping to see who can be the possible recipients and show to user.

Is this a good approach? Or else, Word2Vec (or doc2vec or lda2vec) is better suited for this problem where we can predict similar messages using vector representation of words aka word embeddings? Do we really need to extract topics from the messages to predict the recipients or is that not necessary here? Any other algorithms or techniques you think will work the best?

What are your thoughts and suggestions?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Most probably, this question is more suited for http://datascience.stackexchange.com. Here's a cautionary tale: http://multithreaded.stitchfix.com/blog/2017/10/18/stop-using-word2vec/

Answer (score 1):

Since you are purely looking at topic extraction from previous posts, in my opinion LDA would be a better choice. LDA would describe the statistical relationship of occurrences. Semantics of the words would mostly be ignored (if you are looking for that then you might want to rethink). But also I would suggest to have a look at a hybrid approach. I have not tried it myself but looks quiet interesting.

[lda2vec new hybrid approach](https://www.slideshare.net/ChristopherMoody3/word2vec-lda-and-introducing-a-new-hybrid-algorithm-lda2vec)

Also, if you happen to try it out, would love to know your findings.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for recommender systems (Netflix movie suggestions, amazon purchase recommendations, ect) or Network analysis (Facebook friend recommendations) which utilize topic modeling as an attribute.  I'll try to break them down:

Network Analysis:

FB friends are nodes of a network whose edges are friendship relationships.  Calculates betweenness centrality, finds shortest paths between nodes, stores shortest edges as a list, closeness centrality is the sum of length between nodes.

Recommender Systems:

recommends what is popular, looks at users similar and suggests things that the user might be interested in, calculates cosine similarity by measuring angels between vectors that point in the same direction.

LDA:

topic modeler for text data - returns topics of interest might be used as a nested algorithm within the algorithms above.

Word2Vec:

This is a neccassary step in building an LDA it looks like this:  word -> # say 324 then count frequency say it showed up twice in a sentence:

This is a sentence is.

[(1,1), (2,2), (3,1), (4,1), (2,2)]

It is a neural net you will probably have to use as a pre-processing step.

I hope this helps :)